# How to get from Dulles Airport to Hilton Garden Inn Falls Church

Tags: airport-transfer, iad, virginia

Please advise how to get from Dulles Airport to Hilton Garden Inn Falls Church (706 West Broad Street, Falls Church, Virginia 22046, USA).

Comment: What are your criteria? How many people are traveling? Is price more important or time? Will you have a lot of luggage? What time or day or night? There are a ton of valid options, from hiring a car service to a taxi to Uber/Lyft to SuperShuttle to various public transit options. Which one is right for you will depend on your preferences and needs.

Comment: Idk how far it is, but isn't a cab always a good option?

Comment: For four persons. As it has been my first time to USA, I have no idea how I can go to the hotel in a more convienient way (other than hiring a taxi). Thanks.

Comment: What is more convenient than a cab or a car?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Uber fare estimator](https://www.uber.com/fare-estimate/), it costs around $50 to take an UberXL (larger version of a taxi, since I assume you will need a lot of space).

[image: uber fare]

There are public transport options, but they will cost at least $40 for a group of four and therefore not cost-effective.